# O que é o Quirks Mode e o Standards Mode do Navegador?

Tags: html, css, navegador-de-internet

Vez ou outra eu escuto o termo *Quirks Mode*, mas nunca entendi direito o que isso significa ou o que isso implica na renderização do documento HTML / CSS.

O que ocorre para que a página entre em `Quirks Mode`, e o que é preciso para assegurar que a página está definida no padrão `Standards Mode`?

Como eu faria para "ativar" o `Quirks Mode` de um documento propositalmente? Exite algum motivo técnico para deixar um documento entrar nesse modo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resumindo, o `Quirks Mode` é uma forma de emular os comportamentos de renderização não padrões do Netscape Navigator 4 e Internet Explorer 5. Ele surgiu como uma forma de evitar a quebra de sites criados antes dos padrões web.

A escolha do modo a ser utilizado pelo navegador se dá através do DOCTYPE.

O mais simples e que garante a utilização do `Full Standards Mode` é o `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

A utilização de outro DOCTYPE, como por exemplo, `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" >`, pode levar a utilização do `Almost Standards Mode`.

A não utilização de um DOCTYPE leva a utilização do `Quirks Mode`.

Caso queira saber mais detalhes sobre as diferenças entre os modos recomendo a leitura deste material https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode.